# CD-ROM drive making "tzu tzu" sounds when locating files?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, dvd, compact-disc

My [Acer Aspire 4937G](http://asia.cnet.com/product/acer-aspire-4937g-core-2-duo-t9550-processor-2-66ghz-4gb-ram-44781126.htm)  is making weird sounds whenever I try to browse files from a CD-ROM using windows explorer.

For example, it will go "tzuuu tzuuuu" whenever I click on a file or folder. I have [recorded the sound on Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53jM4a9X2fqR2I2X29kLTI2SDA/edit?usp=sharing) (forward to 0:07 and 0:24 minute marks).

Files can be read normally though, and there are no problems besides the odd sounds.

Is this something to worry about? Is it a sign that my DVD drive needs replacement?

Comment: Not quite sure what a "toot toot toot toot" noise is. Have you tried cleaning the drive? Have you noticed any patterns; does this happen with a specific disk, does this happen with commercial disks or custom burnt ones?

Comment: @CharlieRB, my computer has just returned from a drive repair shop. It didn't used to be able to read CD-ROM, but it can now. Yet, I'm suspecting the repair wasn't done 100% properly and the drive may fail again very soon. This seems to happen more with Windows OEM installation disks.

Comment: Is your laptop on a level surface?

Comment: @Breakthrough, it is on a level surface. My table is a glass surface though, if that matters.

Comment: "Tsk tsk" sounds? Tell it that when you want an editorial from it, you will ask it for one.

Comment: More seriously, confirm when putting discs on the tray that they're well snapped down on all sides of the spindle, and aren't warped; when I've heard (what I suspect to be) similar sounds from my own laptop (an Aspire rebadged as Toshiba), it's been because the disc wasn't level and was making contact with the tray on each revolution. Probably won't hurt the tray, but it certainly won't do the disc any good.

Comment: I would take it back to the repair shop. If you are saying they worked on the CD/DVD drive, it's possible they just replaced it and maybe there is something wrong with the new one. Otherwise, if they took the drive apart to repair it, they obviously did not put it back together correctly.